# Dynamically filter rows based on the value of bit column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

There are two tables:
Student and TeacherSchedule which are are not related.

Student table has a nullable 'NeedsExtraHours' column of type bit.
TeacherSchedule table has non-nullable column 'IsAdHoc' of type bit.

A dynamic query is created in C# which gets a teacher schedules based on TeacherId and other parameters.
The other parameters are omitted here as they are not important for the question.

A snippet of this dynamic SQL is like so:

```cs
    StringBuilder sbCommand = new StringBuilder(2000);
    
    sbCommand.Append("declare @studentNeedsExtraHours bit; ");
    sbCommand.Append(" set @studentNeedsExtraHours = (select ISNULL(NeedsExtraHours,0) from dbo.Student where StudentId = @StudentId); ");
    
    sbCommand.Append(" declare @adhocYN bit; ");
    sbCommand.Append(" set @adhocYN = case when @studentNeedsExtraHours = 0 then  1 else 0 end ");
    
    
    sbCommand.AppendLine(@"SELECT TS.ScheduleId, TS.CourseId FROM TeacherSchedule TS ");
    ...
    if (SessionsSchedules.IsEnabled)
    {
        sbCommand.AppendFormat(@" WHERE TS.CourseId IN (SELECT CourseId FROM dbo.Courses) ");
    }
    else if (SessionsSchedules.IsEnabled && !appFilter.IsSessionsBooking)
    {
        sbCommand.AppendFormat(@" WHERE TS.ScheduleDate >= @StartDate AND TS.CourseId IN (SELECT CourseId FROM dbo.Courses) AND TS.SessionId IS NULL ");
    }
    else
    {
        sbCommand.AppendFormat(@" WHERE TS.ScheduleDate >= @StartDate AND TS.CourseId IN (SELECT CourseId FROM Courses) ");
    }
    
    sbCommand.AppendFormat(@" AND TS.IsAdHoc = @adhocYN ");
```

Part of the dynamic query are these two statements:

```sql
    declare @studentNeedsExtraHours bit
    set @studentNeedsExtraHours = (select ISNULL(NeedsExtraHours,0) from dbo.Student where StudentId = @StudentId)
    
    declare @adhocYN bit
    set @adhocYN = case when @studentNeedsExtraHours = 0 then  1 else 0 end
```

In the WHERE clause it's added like this

```
    WHERE 
    ...
    TS.IsAdHoc = @adhocYN
```

I am not able come up with the logic to achieve this:

If `NeedsExtraHours` is 1 the query should not return AdHoc slots from `TeacherSchedule`.
If `NeedsExtraHours` is 0 all the slots from `TeacherSchedule` table, 1 or 0 are also returned.

Comment: Why is `NeedsExtraHours` a `NULL` column instead of `NOT NULL`?

Comment: @Dai the column type is by design and has existed for some time now. That's all I have as a far as that is concerned. Can't show full T-SQL as it would expose the business. Will post a snippet if it helps.

Comment: _"Can't show full T-SQL as it would expose the business"_ - what happened to students-and-teachers? (and what's stopping you from redacting your T-SQL before posting?)

Comment: Part of the problem is that your generated `SELECT` query is missing the _all-important_ `FROM` clause... - your code skips straight to rendering the `WHERE` clause to the StringBuilder.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using a join, and a simple logic filter

```cs
sbCommand.AppendLine(@"
SELECT
  TS.ScheduleId,
  TS.CourseId
FROM TeacherSchedule TS
JOIN dbo.Student S ON S.StudentId = @StudentId");
```

```cs
sbCommand.AppendLine(@" AND (S.NeedsExtraHours = 0 OR S.NeedsExtraHours IS NULL OR TS.IsAdHoc = 0)");
```